# How to collapse space after cursor in vim

Tags: vim

I have my cursor between two lines in vim:

[image]

I would do this in a 'normal' editor by pressing ctrl-d to delete the characters after the cursor. What would be the most efficient way to do this in vim?

Comment: [please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current cursor is at `,`:

- if you want to remove the linebreak: press `J`
- if you want to remove the ',' : press `x`
- if you want to remove the closing single-quote `'`: press `X`

Comment: cool, understand the `x` and `X`. Could you please explain the `J` ?

Comment: @David542 `:h J`

Comment: is there a way to remote the character directly after the cursor? For example, the opposite of `X` ?

Comment: @David542 I guess you meant "to remove", no, there is no built-in NORMAL command for that. you have to move on the char to remove

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join lines with no space in beewin them press

```
gJ
```

If you want to remove the rest of the line in insert mode:

```
Ctrl-o D
```

To map this action, you can put this on your ~/.vimrc

```
" delete the rest of the current line
inoremap <c-k> <c-o>d
```

I'm not suggesting maping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> because it is already mapped to decrease indenting, in oposition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>